# Boot fails after installing nvidia graphics drivers

Tags: debian, drivers, iwlwifi

[image: error image]

Unfortunately I keep running into this issue when trying to install Debian. It occurs after I install the nvidia graphics drivers as per this guide https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers. I am following the `Version 390.48 (via stretch-backports)` guide and then the configuration steps via `nvidia-xconfig`.

How can I troubleshoot this and get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now managed to fix the issue. On a fresh install of Debian, these were the steps that allowed me to install the Nvidia drivers:

1. Enter `ttyl` mode by pressing CTRL + ALT + F4 or CTRL + ALT + F1
2. Stop the X server with the command `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop`. In my case this was gdm3. You may need to type CTRL + ALT + F4/F1 again to get back into ttyl.
3. Run the cuda installation runfile: `sudo sh ~/Downloads/cuda_<version>_linux.run`
4. Add the suggested variables to `.bashrc`:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-<version>/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-<version>/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
   export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What Nvidia card do you have? Before did you install Nvidia drivers, did you use nouveau drivers?
I had a similar problem with Debian stable and a Dell Inspiron that brings a hybrid graphics card: Intel and Nvidia, and the solution was to force through Xorg.conf that always the X systems start with Nvidia graphics.  But a few months ago, with Debian buster, the problem was gone

Comment: GTX 1080 ti. Nope, I don't think so. Right now I am trying again with the Nvidia drivers from the Nvidia website. I only need my GPU for computing stuff, not display, so I am trying to set the Xorg.conf to use the intel onboard driver instead of nvidia. Probably no help to you unfortunately.